# I have a problem with this code after adding the kick player command. The rest of the bot doesn't work and neither does this command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```js
const { Client, RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");
    const chalk = require("chalk");

    const { token, prefix } = require("../config/config.js");

    const client = new Client();

    client.on("ready", () => {
      console.log(chalk.red("Witamy w konsoli bota Island"));
      console.log(chalk.green(`Zalogowano jako ${client.user.tag}!`));
    });
    client.on("message", (msg) => {
      const { author, guild } = msg;

      if (author.bot || !guild) {
        return;
      }

      if (msg.content === "-info") {
        msg.channel.send("Witam, jestem botem stworzonym przez Rewera");
      }
    });
    client.on("message", (msg) => {
      const { author, guild } = msg;

      if (author.bot || !guild) {
        return;
      }

      if (msg.content === "-komendy") {
        msg.channel.send("Już wkrótce, zostaną dodane. Są w trakcie tworzenia");
      }
      if (msg.content === "-wersja") {
        msg.channel.send("Wersja: ALPHA 0.04");
      }
      if (msg === "-tworca") {
        const botAuthor = "Rewer";
        const botVersion = "v1.1";
        msg.channel.send(
          "Autorem bota jest: **${botAuthor}**! Wersja *${botVersion}*. "
        );
      }
      if (message.content.startsWith("$kick")) {

        if (!message.member.roles.find("name", "Admin"))
            return;
        // Easy way to get member object though mentions.
        var member = message.mentions.members.first();
        // Kick
        member.kick().then((member) => {
            // Successmessage
            message.channel.send(":wave: " + member.displayName + " has been successfully kicked :point_right: ");
        }).catch(() => {
            // Failmessage
            message.channel.send("Access Denied");
        });
    }
    });
    // Error handler
    client.on("debug", () => {});
    client.on("warn", () => {});
    client.on("error", () => {});
    client.login(token);
```

I have a problem with this code after adding the kick player command. The rest of the bot doesn't work and neither does this command

**I don't know what to do with it when I remove the kick code. The bot magically starts working.**

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix it, I'm a beginner so please understand

Comment: why are you using `message` if on the rest of the bot you use `msg`?

Answer (score 0):

When you handle the message event you pass "msg" as the argument

`client.on("message", (msg) => {`

So you should use "msg" throughout

However in you kick command you start using "message"

`if (message.content.startsWith("$kick")) {`
and `if (!message.member.roles.find("name", "Admin"))`

You must change "message" to "***msg***" to match the name you gave the variable at the start
client.on("message", (***msg***) => {